# creating HTML-like labels for GraphViz in Clojure

Tags: clojure, graphviz

Can you create GraphViz's HTML-like labels in Clojure using `rhizome`? 
So far I have found only the library `tangle` to support it.

Comment: See https://github.com/ztellman/rhizome/issues/11 ; naive tests with a defrecord and a print-method or a toString have failed for me

Comment: Well, you've answered my question, so I should accept it as an answer whether it's good or bad news.